# how to catch packet using jpcap?

Tags: java, jpcap

i have installed jpcap and add it in library but i have error in this line:

String[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();

i think I added it wrong because it said: Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    // TODO code application logic here
  String[] devices = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList();
    if(args.length<1){
        System.out.println("Usage: java SentUDP <device index (e.g., 0, 1..)>");
        for(int i=0;i<devices.length;i++)
            System.out.println(i+":"+devices[i].name+"("+devices[i].description+")");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the javadoc for the `deviceList()` method: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/JpcapCaptor.html#getDeviceList()

As you can see, it returns an array of [`NetworkInterface`](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/NetworkInterface.html) objects, not an array of strings.